# How can i change the entire speed (timing) of a android game made with cocos2dx?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, reverse-engineering, ida

i'm making reverse engineering on a android game made with cocos2dx library, editing the .so file (libcocos2dcpp.so) with ida pro and a hex editor. i've getting success changing small things, like swapping buttons functions (changing the jump addresses).

I think this game action too slow, there is someway to increase the speed to entire game? like changing some lib variable and make it accelerate 2x. i think it can be done decreasing a especific delay or increasing the clock cycles, or even changing some fps parameter.

i've readed the documentation of cocos2d and see found some relative functions like getDeltaTime, SetAnimationInterval, CCDirector, CCSpeed, CCAnimation, setTimeScale, etc. but its too many to find the right one trying by trial and error.

Can anyone help me? i will be very thankful